# ring of real functions field or not

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can somebody explain why $\cal{F}(\mathbb{R})$ is not a field nor an integral domain? On what instance does it not satisfy the definition of an integral domain?

Comment: One can see quickly that it is not field, as any function with a root does not have a multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: consider

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \le 0 \\ 0, & x>0\end{cases}$$

and

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \le 0 \\ 1, & x>0\end{cases}.$$

What do you know about $fg$? (You can adapt this to even work for continuous (or even smooth) functions.)

Comment: Just use $1-x, x \leq 0, x $ if $x>0$.OR, more dramatic: $ \chi \mathbb Q  \chi (\mathbb R - \mathbb Q)$

Answer (score 0):

If the ring multipliction is composition, then consider the function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R : f(x)=1 , \forall x \in \mathbb R$ , what is its inverse?

Maybe you meant actual multiplication in the ring. If this is the case, consider any function that takes the value $0$, e.g., $f(x)=x$. Then there is no
$g$ with $fg=1$, with $1$ the identity function $f(x)==1$.

Comment: I'm thinking you mean something else by $f$ than what you've written. That function does have an inverse.

Comment: I mean the constant function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that sends every number to $1$. Just an extreme case of a non-bijective function.

Comment: Isn't it its own inverse since it is the unit in the ring of functions? Edit: I think I see where we are disagreeing. Inverse here should mean multiplicative inverse, not inverse function. The operation of function composition doesn't play nicely with the linear structure.

Comment: Since s/he mentioned a ring, I assumed  multiplication, but I will consider composition.

Comment: O.K, I considered the function $f(x)==0$, which takes care of both possibilities.

Comment: Even your correction is incorrect. The function $f(x) = 0$ is the additive identity so it doesn't (can't) have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: What do you mean by _even_ ? It is not clear in the OP what the ring multiplication is.

Comment: OP did not state what the multiplication is, but the space of functions on $\Bbb R$ has attached to it the natural addition and multiplication that it inherits from $\Bbb R$. This edit I agree with and is definitely the best example for showing inverses don't exist, I think. That said, function composition cannot play the role of multiplication since it doesn't obey the ring properties.

Comment: Isnt $f \circ (g+h)=f\circ g +f \circ h$ and $ (h+g) \circ f =h \circ f +g \circ f $?

Comment: No. Consider $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x = h(x)$. Then $f(g(x)+h(x)) = f(2x) = 4x^2$ but $f(g(x))+f(h(x)) = x^2 + x^2 = 2x^2$.

Comment: I guess I jumped in too quickly. But of course, there is the approval of those trashing my post. Welcome to mathstack exchange.

Comment: No worries! It's an easy mistake to make. I think your second point is a good one worth keeping as an answer since it addresses a very important aspect of function spaces.